# internet in alpine virtualbox in macos

Tags: osx, virtualbox, alpine-linux

I am installing `alpine 3.4.6` os in `virtualbox 5`. I got following network adaptors,

[image]

But none of these are allowing to have internet in the virtualbox.

I chose to use `dhcp` while setting up using `alpine-setup`.
[image]

The `setup-alpine` itself is failing not being able to find fastest mirror url.

[image]

Network config is,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For those that have this problem and are installing `Alpine for VM` you have to do this:
First run `setup-alpine` and go on and then you will hit the problem.
After that this setup has filled the file `/etc/network/interfaces` for you.
Now do this:

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

and In the part of the file that it has written:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Just add `udhcpc_opts -O search` below it like this:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    udhcpc_opts -O search
```

Then run this:

```
ifup eth0
```

If it says its currently up then you need to `down` it first:

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

Then :)

```
ping google.com
```

HTH, Have a nice day!

Comment: in my alpine yell `ping: add address google.com` , do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, my internet is killing me. Its internet issue, I changed my network and and its working with `bridge mode`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use your principal interface
to discover
use `ifconfig` from cli/terminal
and see which has ip configured.